# Refresh JSON store Every 60 Sec - EXT JS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, extjs4

```
    var MarkerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            model: 'GoogleMarkerModel',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'get-googlemarker.php',
                baseParams: {  //here you can define params you want to be sent on each request from this store
                            mainid: 'value1'
                            },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    idProperty:'MainID',
                }

            }
        });

setTimeout(MarkerStore, 60000);
```

is this correct?because i still can't get any new data every 60 sec

Answer (score 3):

I just use the javascript `setInterval` function. Sencha uses this themselves in their [livegrid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/charts/LiveAnimated.html) example.

For example:

```
// reload the stores once and then repeatedly every 60 seconds
MarkerStore.load();
setInterval(function() {
    MarkerStore.load();
}, 60000);
```

For a more complete answer, the `setTimeout` javascript function you were using only executes the code once after the designated number of milliseconds. `setInterval` is what you want to repeatedly execute a *function*.

Also note that the first argument of both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` is a javascript function. In your code snippet above, you are passing the store object itself as the first argument which would not result in it getting called at all. [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) has more data.